# Server Request Time out with Spray

Tags: timeout, apache-spark, spray

I am working on a simple spray REST application with spark and I have the following code (generated from spray-template). I modified it to include json support and some recommender program which returns List of Businesses. For some reason the request times out even though I specified the timeout parameter to infinite. can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ? looks like I took a wrong choice of technologies and the support is very less in the forums. The recommender runs in the background though server returns immediately to the client with timeout error. I played with lot of configuration values but still doesn't seem to like it. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
case class Business(name:String)
object MyProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport{
  implicit val elementFormat = jsonFormat1(Business)
}

trait MyService extends HttpService {
import MyProtocol._ 

val myRoute = {

      path("") {
        get {
          respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
            complete(Recommender.recommend(1000)) // times out 
            complete('some html') // works immediately 
          }
   }
}

def Recommend(userId: Int) : List[Business] = {
  ......................
}

application.conf 

spray.can {
    server {
     request-timeout = infinite
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example works for me: https://gist.github.com/jrudolph/e6bb940a341f46873cd5. The request timeout isn't the only timeout setting. There's also the `spray.can.server.idle-timeout` you may want to set.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
// In some file, define yopur model
case class Business(name: String, age: Int)
object MyProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport{
  implicit val elementFormat = jsonFormat2(Business)
}

// In other file
trait MyService extends HttpService {
  import MyProtocol._ 

  val myRoutes = {
    path("sthnotverytimeconsuming") {
      get {
        complete {
          doRequest()
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("sthverytimeconsuming") {
      get {
        complete {
          doTimeConsumingRequest()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private def doRequest(): Future[List[Business]] = {
    Future{
      val result : List[Business] = // ... do something that take times but not very long
      result
    }
  }

  private def doTimeConsumingRequest(): Future[List[Business]] = {
    Future{
      // ... you can do something that take a long time here
    }
    val result : List[Business] = //...
    result //... this will return immediately
  }
}
```